# Serilog Configuration on Classic ASP.Net (NOT CORE)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, serilog

I am trying to use Serilog in ASP .Net Framework not core with SQL Server Database but I can't add any new records to my table in database is shown below and the code for logging also.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo
            .MSSqlServer(
                connectionString: "Server=DESKTOP-A9EBI4L;Database=SvuCommon_Alternate;Integrated Security=SSPI;",
                sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "EventLog" })
            .CreateLogger();
            Log.Information("{Message}","sdfs" );

            try
            {
                int a = 1, b = 0;
                Log.Debug("The value aer{0} and {1}", a, b);
               


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, "some Error!");
            }
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Done");
```

[image: table design]

Comment: The table shown in your image doesn't seem to match [the recommend table schema](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#table-definition).

Comment: I saw this befor but I need to see the exact table I add some config after that but nw I get an exception

Comment: tha table that your are take about is working for me but when I want to change it ,it is not work

Comment: Serilogs documentation describes how to enable the self log. That may give you insight as to the exact problem. https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog